# Domain name resolves to IP address

Tags: domain-name-system, ip-address, domain-name

I wanted to get clarity on this issue (instead of the usual try-stuff-till-it's-fixed approach). As a developer and curious person I really want to understand what's going on here so I can thoughtfully fix it.

The Problem:

I bought a domain name and pointed it to my site. Typing the domain name in the address bar does take you to the site, but the IP address still shows. I want to make it so that the domain name shows instead.

This problem was not happening for a while, but after not really checking up on the site, this is suddenly happening.

A Few Details:

The site is a wordpress site, hosted on digitalocean. The domain is from google (before they sold google domains to squarespace).

Ask me for any information I neglected to add here. Thanks for your help! Here's a screenshot of the DNS info: [image]

Answer (score 1):

> Domain name resolves to IP address

It always does; that's the entire purpose of DNS. But this would not change what you see in the address bar.

> Typing the domain name in the address bar does take you to the site, but the IP address still shows. I want to make it so that the domain name shows instead.

That's **not** a DNS problem and has nothing to do with the domain name "resolving to" the address. If your address bar changes by itself, that's the actual website redirecting you elsewhere – it might be an HTTP 30x redirect, an HTML <meta refresh>, a JavaScript thing, but certainly not DNS.

Most likely the blog engine has a setting for "website domain" or something similar, and deliberately redirects visitors if they somehow reach it through the "wrong" address.

I'm not familiar with WordPress configuration but I searched for "wordpress redirects to ip address" and it says that you can find that under [Settings > General](https://serverpilot.io/docs/solution-to-wordpress-showing-ip-address-instead-of-domain/) or in your `wp-config.php` (WP_SITEURL and WP_HOME).

Comment: Thank you for correcting the terminology I used. No one has changed the site settings / wp-config file, so I doubt the solution would involve either.

Comment: There are several places in WordPress where the domain can be configured, you need to check them all. And most likely it is WordPress that does this redirect.